# A function using a for loop that sums up numbers in a list, before reaching a specific number

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I would like to use a `for` loop to go through a list of numbers and stop when it reaches a specific number like `4`, returning the sum of the numbers that came before it.

So if the list is `[1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2]`, the function would return `3` after summation.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what exactly is the problem with it? SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways (*with* and *without* function) using `for` loop. The `if` condition will break out of the `for` loop as soon as element will be `4`, otherwise it will keep summing. Coming out of the `for` loop, you can print the sum `s`

**Without function**

```
lst = [1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2]
s = 0
for l in lst:
    if l == 4:
        break
    s += l

print ("The sum is %d" %s) 

> The sum is 3
```

**With function**

```
lst = [1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2]
num = 4

def summ(lst, num):
    s = 0
    for l in lst:
        if l == num:
            return s
        s += l

print ("The sum is %d" %summ(lst, num))   

> The sum is 3
```

Comment: Thank you just what i needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from itertools import takewhile

res = sum(takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, [1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2]))  # 3
```

The [docs for `itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) give the equivalent generator which can be used to implement the logic directly:

```
def takewhile(predicate, iterable):
    # takewhile(lambda x: x < 4, [1, 2, 4, 0, 3, 2]) --> 1 2
    for x in iterable:
        if predicate(x):
            yield x
        else:
            break
```

Comment: The OP says `for` loop.

Comment: ;) Great. ...... I have to add dots because there is a minimum limit of characters :)